# No se me guardar los datos en el localStorage cuando recargo la pagina

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, variables-globales

¡Buenas! Estoy haciendo un proyecto con React y JS, una especie de juego de preguntas que cada vez que aciertas te lleva a la siguiente, el problema viene aqui:

Tengo declarado un localStorage en la pagina principal de rondas que comienza en 1, siempre que entras en la pagina. Cuando llegas a la primera pregunta, si aciertas tengo puesto un contador de que se sume el numero de rondas y se guarde en el localStorage, para cuando si acierto la pregunta recargue la pagina y ese me traiga el valor del localStorage (En este caso seria 2) para subir el nivel de dificultad de la pregunta, el problema es cuando recargo la pagina se pierde el valor y se vuelve a poner a numero 1 y así sucesivamente.. ¿Alguna solución? Dejo por aqui mi codigo:

**HOME.JS**

```
> localStorage.setItem("numRounds", 5)
```

**PREGUNTAS.JS**

```
>         if (answerCorrect == answerUser){
              var numeroRounds = localStorage.getItem("numRounds");
>             alert("¡Has acertado! Siguiente pregunta")
>             numeroRounds++
>             localStorage.setItem("numRounds", numeroRounds);
>             window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/pregunta");
>         }
```

¡Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 4):

el problema es que localStorage siempre guarda como string entonces lo que pasa es lo siguiente:

```
localStorage.setItem('numRounds', 1)

var numeroRounds = localStorage.getItem('numRounds')

// numeroRounds = "1"
```

al aplicar el operando "++" al numeroRounds que es un texto lo que hace es convertirlo a número

```
numeroRounds++

// numeroRounds = 1
```

luego vuelves a guardar el numero 1

```
localStorage.setItem('numRounds', numeroRounds)
// recordar que numeroRounds es 1
```

y el ciclo se repite nuevamente lo que te deja siempre en 1

lo que debes hacer es hacer un parse al texto guardado en localStorage

```
var numeroRounds = Number.parseInt(localStorage.getItem('numRounds'))
```